# Restricting an HTML table to scroll in one direction in iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a basic HTML table and the width and height are both restricted so that it scrolls both vertically and horizontally.

Everything works fine, but on iPad, a user is able to scroll around in all directions (including diagonally). This isn't great. I'd like to restrict scrolling to one direction at a time. Is it possible with HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery? Plugins are fine.

I'm also using KendoUI Grids for the table, if that makes any difference.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/km6CN/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some code so I can post JS Fiddle link</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pure CSS by adding `overflow-x:hidden;` to your code. This completely disables left/right scrolling.

```
#restricted {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-x: hidden;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fizk/Srv7N/

If you want to enable/disable scroll programmatically, you could very well use jQuery to do so;

```
$("#restriceted").css("overflow-x","hidden");
// Restricting to only up/down scroll
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Especially useful with something like jGestures - http://jgestures.codeplex.com/.